# Creating a new Cocos2d-x Project is over 200mb! How to create a more bare-bones template?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Really, the template new project that is created, as described in the Cocos2d-x documentation, creates a massive 200+ megabyte project which hurts my hard drive. I tried deleting stuff, but of course it will give tons of errors because things are missing. So I want someone to give me a reasonable way to create a bare-bones cocos2d-x template, perhaps 20MB or less.

Compare it to a Cocos2d-iPhone template, which is like, only 5 MB.

Very confused, and, just looking for a straightforward way to make a basic new game that isn't huge. It's the same for Cocos2dx-html5. If you take the open source test game "Moon Warriors," it's like, over 300MB. How in the world am I going to fit a 300MB Demo game on my website?

Comment: 200 MB hurt your hard drive in an age where even netbooks come with hundreds of gigabytes of disk space?

Comment: Sort of... The MacBook Air only has 120GBs. The problem isn't having one project... the problem is having multiple builds, each with git. Every time I upload to a new project to git, it takes almost an hour. You're right, it's not a big deal, but it would be nicer if you could make smaller Cocos Project templates without all the inflation

Comment: okay uploading certainly is a problem. Well you could remove all unneeded code (scenes in particular) and note which resources they use and remove exactly those after successfully removing the code.

Comment: The only scene is the hello world scene. Literally. I *only* want the hello world scene, and the basic (minimal) cocos2d-x library (which is about 9.5mb). The second I try removing extensions and headers that are not in use, it's a never-ending cascade of errors.

Comment: I can't imagine the source files will amount to more than 10 megabytes. My guess is there'll be a host of image files, whether used by the project or not, that account for at least 80% of the size. Use "Disk Inventory X" app to analyze the folder structure and find out what the largest files/folders are. Also, don't confuse the project folder you have on disk with the compiled, publishable project (the app).

Comment: I can also imagine that cocos2d-x is storing temporary build products (.o and .a files and others) within the project's folder. So question is what is the size after installing the template project but before compiling it the first time?

Comment: Thanks for tending to this question. After compiling it on Mac/iOS, it's about >1GB. I'm not kidding. Before compiling it's 250MB.

Comment: Ouch :( I suggest to take this to the -x dev forum, maybe they can help.

Comment: My solution for git was having cocos2d-x as a submodule. That way the only thing stored in the project's repository are the Classes, proj.* and Resources directories.

Comment: I also found it frustrating that the framework is huge. It's mainly for libraries for JS support, Android and Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cocos2d-x framework is quite large. If you have a project already working, I'd say you could remove the `docs`, `licenses`, `plugins`, `templates`, `tests`, `tools` as well as there are some misc text files like `Authors`, `ChangeLog`, etc.

I tried and that shaved off 500MB for me. I compiled cocos2d_libs.xcodeproj just fine.

Comment: Cocos2d-x v3.6, I have 4.70gb worth of disk space when creating single project. 500mb didn't sound much to me. Have you tried deleting some more in the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

1. After `cocos new` you can remove `cocos2d` folder inside new project, and create a symlink to unzipped `cocos2d-x` folder:

   rm -rf cocos2d; ln -s /path/to/cocos2d-x cocos2d

This makes 3Mb-14Mb project folder, which can be copied instead of `cocos new`

2. To improve build size and time it's possible to use prebuilt cocos2d-x library.

   In your project `CMakeLists.txt` remove `add_subdirectory(${COCOS2D_ROOT})` and add `link_directories(/path/to/libcocos2d)` `include_directories(/path/to/cocos2d-x/cocos /path/to/cocos2d-x/extensions)`. Run `cmake ..&& make`.

   This may error in many undefined references, resolve them by adding libs to `taget_link_libraries()`. Also it may require setting some options in cocos2d-x `CMakeLists.txt` to `OFF` before prebuilding libcocos2d.